# What do you call this low-detail illustration style?

Tags: illustration, style-identification

This kind of style with few details?
Preferable abstract with very few face details.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **Thresholding** or **Stenciling**. At its most basic, you are radically compressing a wide range of color values to a smaller number.

It is a form of Image Segmentation.

> "Done with stencil and spraypaint."

http://galleryofthrones.tumblr.com/post/45440739671/jon-snow-the-warg-of-winterfell-by-ali-radicali